# jquery datatables numeric sorting

Tags: jquery, sorting, datatable

I have fetched data from database in descending order 
and formatted in datatable it is being shown in random order it is sorting it as string

My requirements

1. sort by 1st column descending order considering it numeric
2. disable sorting on last column
3. in between these 2, number of columns may vary

OR simply disable ordering data on page load, display it as it is but keep enabled columns order-able

I tried many things but could not find

Curently I am having

```
$('#dataTables-example').dataTable({
           'aoColumnDefs': [{
                'bSortable': false,
                'aTargets': [-1],
            }]
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the following code will disable initial sorting and disable sorting of lat column

```
    $('#dataTables-example').dataTable({
                "aaSorting": [],

                'aoColumnDefs': [{
                    'bSortable': false,
                    'aTargets': [-1],
                }]
    });
```